# Compiling simpleChat.C from Wt Example Error

Tags: c, compilation, g++, wt

I made changes in **simpleChat.C** file removing "*I'm schizophrenic ...*" Button. of [simplechat example](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/src/simplechat) from [wt in Ubuntu](http://redmine.emweb.be/projects/wt/wiki/Installing_Wt_on_Ubuntu).

And tried compiling it with command:

```
sudo g++ -o simplechat simpleChat.C -lwthttp -lwt
```

Error:

> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccHOujNG.o: undefined reference to symbol
>   '_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv'
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.55.0: error adding
>   symbols: DSO missing from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status

also adding `-lboost_signals`
gives same error

after this error, it removes the earlier ./simplechat executable Since its overwriting it and was not able to complete..

I was able to successfully compile & execute hello.c with same command.

Any type of help reffering me on how I can succesfully compile simpleChat.C would be Great..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok..
So we have to include all other .C files and all necessary Libraries.

Libraries we need:

```
-lwthttp -lwt -lboost_system -lboost_signals -pthread
```

all .C files

```
simpleChat.C PopupChatWidget.C SimpleChatWidget.C SimpleChatServer.C
```

Here it is all for Compiling:

```
sudo g++ -o simplechat simpleChat.C PopupChatWidget.C SimpleChatWidget.C SimpleChatServer.C -lwthttp -lwt -lboost_system -lboost_signals -pthread
```

Then you can execute it by:

```
sudo ./simplechat --docroot . --http-address 0.0.0.0 --http-port 8080
```

Comment: No need to _sudo_ here though

Answer (score 1):

`_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv` means you are missing `-lboost_system`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add -lboost_system, and try again.